# CollectionProperty initialization

Tags: python

i need to initialize a CollectionProperty with a fixed number of items. This property is 
used to store slot data, kind of like texture slots (There is 18 slots avaibles, but even if they are empty, they exist in the slot collection). Not sure if i am very clear so here is a bit of code

```
class MyPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_space_type = "PROPERTIES"
    bl_region_type = "WINDOW"
    bl_context = "world"
    bl_label = "my panel"
    bl_options = {'DEFAULT_CLOSED'}

    def draw_header(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row()

        ob = context.active_object

        # tried to initialize the collection here but i get the error "Writing to ID classes in this context is not allowed"
        """if(len(ob.test.myslots) < 4):
            for i in range(len(ob.test.myslots), 4):
                ob.test.myslots.add()"""
    # MyUIList inherit from bpy.types.UIList
        layout.template_list("MyUIList", "", ob.test, "myslots", ob.test, "myslots_active", rows=4, maxrows=4)

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return (context.active_object is not None and context.active_object.data is not None and isinstance(context.active_object.data, bpy.types.Mesh))


class MySlot(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    slotName = bpy.props.StringProperty()

class MyProperty(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    myslots = bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=MySlot)
    myslots_active = bpy.props.IntProperty()

bpy.types.Object.test = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=MyProperty)
```

How do I inititalize this list so...?

Comment: Can you explain more about how you would want the list initialized? initialized as empty? as entirely filled?

Comment: doesn't matter...

Answer (score 2):

You can't, you need to have an explicit operation to initialize the list. (a button for example), or when the script executes.

At least you can't do while drawing.

Comment: It is possible using a hack: a scene update handler that removes itself and adds the required items, although there can be issues if you load another .blend file. Another workaround is to use an EnumProperty with items-callback and handle the CollectionProperty there too.

Comment: @CodeManX EnumProperty with items-callback doesn't work. It gives error `doesn't allowed to write data in this context`.